# Variable name of a data frame in R

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, automation, declare

I want to create numerous data.frames so I wanted to automate it a bit.

```
## Some Loop   
i = i + 1
(paste('df',i,sep = '')) = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 1))
## Do some Task
```

If I initialise *i* to 1, then for N passes through the loop I will create *df1*, *df2* ... *dfN*.

But this doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas how I can fix my code/ a different approach I could look at?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: You should store the dataframes in a data structure such as a list, which you should initialize outside of your loop

Comment: Or you can use `assign` to assign the data.frame to a name defined by a string (as you are trying to do) - but yeedle's list approach is usually more sensible.

Comment: Thank you for your help folks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  d = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 1))
  assign(paste("df", i, sep = ""), d)
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you every so much!